# Enhanced ecommerce plugin doesn't send ecommerce data to google

Tags: google-analytics, enhanced-ecommerce

I am trying to implement the `enhanced ecommerce plugin`. but my ecommerce data is not reflecting in the `Google Analytics web interface.
Below is my script I included in the header page.

```
(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
(i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
})(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');


ga('create', 'UA-xxxxxxxx-1', 'auto',{'name': 'newTracker'});
ga('newTracker.require', 'ec');

ga('ec:addPromo', {
        'id': 'xyz', // Promotion ID - Required Type: string
        'name': 'test', // Promotion Name - Type: string
        'creative':'', // Creative ad used for promotion - Type: string
        'position':''  // Position of the creative ad - Type: string
}); 


ga('newTracker.send', 'pageview');
```

---

[image]

Above is debug output. I have old plugin use a different ID and new plugin use a different ID. Both are in different `js` files. but trigger same time with user events. I see error below `aborting hit`. I am not sure is this the old or new plugin aborting the `hit` or should I ignore that?

Another thing need to highlight. I have `Google Tag manager` implemented. Does this crash with `ecommerce plugin` ?

Comment: You definitely can't be ignoring your error messages, especially if they're related to analytics. Not clear on what mean by 'old plugin' and 'new plugin' IDs. GA doesn't clash with GTM but why not have it done through GTM in the first place? Also even though classic GA can coexist with UA, you need to be careful about how you are doing that.

Comment: @nyuen  What I mean by old and new is,  new - `Enahanced Ecommerce plugin` but old is classic `Ecommerce Plugin` but still it uses the `'https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga'` so both are in my code in different `js` files.

Comment: I would say clean up the implementation a bit first. There could definitely be some errors when you've got both versions of GA (classic and UA) and also both versions of ecomm (standard and enhanced). Stick to just UA, get rid of the classic (you'll need to do this sooner or later anyway), and focus just either on Standard Ecom or Enhanced (I would go with the latter if you have the time to implement it all and make full use of enhanced).

Answer (score 0):

I had to set everywhere `newTracker`

```
 ga('create', 'UA-77806616-1', 'auto',{'name': 'newTracker'});
 ga('newTracker.require', 'ec');

ga('newTracker.ec:addPromo', {
        'id': 'xyz1', // Promotion ID - Required Type: string
        'name': 'name2', // Promotion Name - Type: string
        'creative':'', // Creative ad used for promotion - Type: string
        'position':''  // Position of the creative ad - Type: string
 });
```